How to switch from one layout to another layout in PyQt5 at runtime In a clear manner for beginner
Using the following process the following code fails.
Setup:
First create a container QWidget with HBox layout and two buttons.
When the first button is clicked, switch to VBox layout.
To switch layouts:

Create a list of child widgets and remove them from the current layout.
Create a new layout.
Add the widgets from list to the new layout.
Set container widget to new layout.

Note:

setParent(None) for children is ineffective.
setLayout(None) for children is invalid.
del old layout is ineffective.

Pseudo code test program: s=self, w=widget, wl=widget list
    import sys   
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *  
    class Lw(QWidget): 
      def __init__(s):
        QWidget.__init__(s)      
        s.lay=QHBoxLayout(); s.setLayout(s.lay) 
        s.setGeometry(50,45,220,220)  
        bu0=QPushButton(); bu0.setText("Switch to VBox"); s.lay.addWidget(bu0)
        bu0.clicked.connect(s.rslay)  
        bu1=QPushButton(); bu1.setText("Dummy"); s.lay.addWidget(bu1)
        s.show()
      
      def rslay(s):  
        wl=[] 
        while s.lay.count()>0: 
          w=s.lay.takeAt(0).widget()
          wl.append(w)
          w.setParent(None) # Ineffective  
          #w.setLayout(None) # Invalid  
        #del s.lay # Ineffective
        s.lay=QVBoxLayout() 
        s.setLayout(s.lay)  
        for w in wl: s.lay.addWidget(w)  
    
    if __name__== '__main__':
      app=QApplication(sys.argv) 
      lw=Lw()
      sys.exit(app.exec()

Program will error:
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Lw "", which already has a layout
The child widgets original layout is not dissociated - even if the layout is deleted or its parent is set to None.

del only removes a Python reference, does not delete an object: that's the garbage collector's responsibility. w.setLayout(None) is also pointless, since w is a child widget. You should use s.lay.setParent(None). In any case, if you just want to switch from horizontal and vertical box layout, then there's absolutely no need to replace the layout: just use setDirection(): s.lay.setDirection(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom) to make it vertical, s.lay.setDirection(QBoxLayout.LeftToRight) to make it horizontal.

yes setDirection() would work in that case. But I will be switching from Boxes to Splitters and to setGeometry.   s.lay.setParent(None) does not remove the link/connection between the widget and the old layout. The program error remains.

Assuming that by "Splitters" you mean QSplitter, that's irrelevant: QBoxLayout is a layout, QSplitter is a widget (with an internal layout management, but that's another story). And if you're using layout managers at any level, setGeometry() should not be used, unless you really know what you're doing. In any case, a possibility is to force the reparenting with QWidget().setLayout(s.lay) after all child items (including nested layouts) have been taken.

The solution by the 'duplicate' is correct. Adding a temp QWidget and settting the layout to it. twidget=QWidget();    twidget.setLayout(s.lay)  # Key item !!!! This line goes under the while loop (after the end).
musicmante. Please know that with PyQtGraph PyCuda and cupy experience, geometry()  is essential. like for resizing dragging and dropping into containers. If my attitude discounted you suggestion,  then sorry and I deserve lesser stackflow reputation.

You don't need a reference for that temporary QWidget, since you'll immediately destroy it anyway, QWidget().setLayout(s.lay) should suffice. I don't know what you meant with your last phrase, but I wasn't offended. Still, real drag&drop has nothing to do with layout management, and resizing of widget should always deal with their size hints, policies or restraints. I don't know about PyCuda/cupy, but if you're using them in Qt then that they are standard widgets or extended ones (like the QGraphicsView internally used by pyqtgraph): as such, if used in a layout, setGeometry() should »

» not be used, as it's the layout's responsibility to do so. If you need to call setGeometry(), then there's probably something wrong in the implementation of the widgets you're using, or in your usage of layouts. While there are rare occasions for which manually setting the geometry along with a layout manager can become necessary, they are specific exceptions probably needed by custom (and, to some extent, possibly unreliable) behavior. If, instead, no layout is used, then it's another story, but 99.9% of the time it's done for the wrong reasons, and lack of knowledge about layouts.

If you have floating, movable, re-sizable, and nested widgets without a layout setGeometry() is needed.  When you drop a widget onto a widget without a layout you account for the offset changes with setGeometry(). I think the phrase 'layout's responsibility to do so' is the issue. The user can be in charge of the position and size of a widget when it is not in a layout. I admit most programs of wide use need to be bullet-proof and really really limit the users ability to modify the layout. What I'm doing is design time at run time. It will not see production, so the audience is different.

Then your note about pyqtgraph/PyCuda was completely irrelevant, as the remark about the difference in usage with "splitters or boxes": I explicitly written since the beginning that if you do use layouts, calling setGeometry() is wrong; so, if you don't use them, whatever the reason, it's quite obvious that you must call it. And the widget type is almost irrelevant, so it doesn't really matter if you're dealing with basic Qt widgets or custom ones (whether built by you or somebody else), they're still QWidget subclasses, so your "geometry() is essential" distinction was simply pointless.

I'm sorry you feel so strongly that layouts must have Layouts. Multiple document interfaces depend on Layout-less  layouts. Precision size and placement requires. Let's do a truce on this. Please  feel free to have the last word.

You don't understand. As said, there are reasons for which not using layout managers is acceptable (and you never mentioned the MDI aspect, by the way), but your remark about pyqtgraph is completely irrelevant, as the point would remain for any kind of widget. The point is being precise in explanations: 1. you asked about switching layout managers, then setGeometry() is irrelevant; 2. noting that "with PyQtGraph PyCuda and cupy experience, geometry() is essential" is pointless, and fundamentally wrong.
